# Is it possible to create a UWP app for different windows 10 builds?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I use *"NavigationView"* in my project but It works in windows 10 build 16299 or higher so I should use *"SplitView"* for lower builds.
Now I like to know :
Is it possible to create a UWP app for different windows 10 builds?

Comment: Have you checked this? [Conditional XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml)

Comment: @AndreyAshikhmin, sadly, conditional XAML is available starting with the Creators Update (version 1703, build 15063). So, no much value can be added that way in terms of per-SDK-version customization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is: yes, you can build different versions of your app package that target different ranges of Windows 10 build numbers. For example you can submit a package that targets 16299 and another one for 15063 and below. The Store will then deliver the right package to the user.

However, a better way to accomplish the same result is to make your app adaptive to the OS version, as explained on MSDN here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-apps

Starting with build 15063 version adaptive code can also be used in XAML, as explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml